# If I want to use Push SDK from Airship, Do I need to have Huawei Developer Account?

Tags: urbanairship.com

Is using Firebase and Airship Dashboard, SDK enough?
Or need new Huawei account for myself?

Answer (score 0):

We need to get our own Huawei Developer account and create an app project.
then we can get push client id and secret to provide to airship in dashboard.
after that the SDK will work the same way as firebase app.